# Mongodb aggregate documents by date when date is in unix time stamp

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

Am new to mongodb so this must be straight forward query.
I have collection as below where date is stored in unix miliseconds

```
[
      {
        "createdAt": 1596700221742,
        "id": "5f2bb63da9babddd420d0fa6",
        "quoteId": "SBA0005",
        "commission": 0,
      },
      {
        "createdAt": 1596699868976,
        "id": "5f2bb4dcbcf1acdbb64137d0",
        "quoteId": "SBA0004",
        "commission": 0,
      },
      {
        "createdAt": 1596698702729,
        "id": "5f2bb04ebcf1acdbb64137ce",
        "quoteId": "SBA0003",
        "commission": 0,
      },
      {
        "createdAt": 1596200445326,
        "id": "5f2415fd9f248110a290aa29",
        "quoteId": "SBA0002",
        "commission": 100,
      },
      {
        "createdAt": 1596200404548,
        "id": "5f2415d49f248110a290aa28",
        "quoteId": "SBA0001",
        "commission": 100,
      },
      {
        "createdAt": 1596200326783,
        "id": "5f2415869f248110a290aa27",
        "quoteId": "SBA0000",
        "commission": 10,
      }
    ]
```

And i would like to get the result grouped by each day when last week data was asked.

```
[{
date: '06-08-2020',
count: 1,
totalcommision: 100},
{
date: '07-08-2020',
count: 2,
totalcommision: 1000
}]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) to convert the date stored in Unix milliseconds. Below is the aggregation query.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "cdate": {
        "$toDate": "$createdAt"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "ddate": {
        "$concat": [
          {
            "$toString": {
              $dayOfMonth: "$cdate"
            }
          },
          "-",
          {
            "$toString": {
              $month: "$cdate"
            }
          },
          "-",
          {
            "$toString": {
              $year: "$cdate"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "commission": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$ddate",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "totalCommision": {
        "$sum": "$commission"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "date": "$_id",
      "count": 1,
      "totalCommision": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kThoerjJMEk) for you.

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a champ. Thank you